# Filter detail table depending on value in header table with a CASE statement

Tags: sql, switch-statement

Depending on a value in a header table, I would like to select a different set of the detail table. If the status of the header table is `2` or greater, it should select the details with a status of `2` or greater. 
Note that de values are not always equal.

Example simplified statement

```
SELECT * FROM DETAIL d
INNER JOIN HEADER h on h.key=d.key

WHERE CASE WHEN h.status < 2 THEN d.status <2 ELSE d.status >=2 END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the detail lines wich correspond to the status of the header with a simple `OR`-statement.

```
SELECT * FROM DETAIL d
INNER JOIN HEADER h on h.key=d.key

WHERE ( (h.status >=2 AND d.status >=2) OR (h.status <2 AND d.status <2) )
```

Because you only select one value for the header table, only one of the two clauses will be True and select those detail lines.